# Given: X ~ Gaussian($\mu$, $\sigma^{2}$) and Y = $e^{X}$. Compute $E(Y)$ and $Var(Y)$.

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Not sure how to start this problem at all. Could someone help?

Comment: Moment generating function might help.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: $\mathbb E[f(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) p_X(x) \, dx$. Then use this and $\operatorname{Var}(X) = \mathbb E[X^2] - \mathbb E[X]^2$.

Comment: We like to see questions that show some form of *context*.  This can take the form of showing your work, explaining how you came across the problem, or detailed explanation of what is confusing you.  This helps us help you better.

Answer (score 1):

- For $\mathbb{E}[Y]$, we have

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[Y]\ &=\ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^x\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-(x - \mu)^2 / 2\sigma^2} dx \\
&=\ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{\mu + y}\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{-y^2 / 2\sigma^2}dy \\
&=\ e^\mu\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^\frac{-y^2 + 2\sigma^2y}{2\sigma^2} dy \\
&=\ e^\mu\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^\frac{-(y - \sigma^2)^2 + \sigma^4}{2\sigma^2} dy \\
&=\ e^\mu e^{\sigma^2/2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^\frac{-(y - \sigma^2)^2}{2\sigma^2} dy \\
&=\ e^{\mu + \frac{\sigma^2}{2}}
\end{align}
For the second equality, we use transform $y = x - \mu$.

- For $\mathbb{E}[Y^2]$, you can derive it similarly and the result is $\mathbb{E}[Y^2] = e^{2\mu + 2\sigma^2}$.
- Use $Var[Y] = \mathbb{E}[Y^2] - \mathbb{E}[Y]^2$ to obtain $Var[Y]$ then.

> **Note:** Given a normal random variable $X$, the random variable $Y = e^X$ follows log-normal distribution.